# How do you trigger an animation with a button in React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, events, onclick

So, I'm trying to make text fade in and out when you press a button; you press it, and the text fades out to be replaced with new text that fades in.

I've done this previously with CSS's hover pseudo-class only, as there is no pseudo-class specifically used for on-click events. Rather, there are pseudo-classes like one that's used for detecting whether a checkbox has been checked, but I want to see if there is a way to handle the event without using any "hack" (e.g. using the checkbox event) or overhead.

EDIT:

Here's the section of code that will likely be responsible for the animation (a button is rendered, updating the quote on the screen).

```
  showQuote() {
    this.props.showNextQuote(QUOTES[rnd()]);
    this.setState({ quote: this.props.quote });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="quote-box" style={boxStyle}>
        <h1>
          <strong>On One Hand...</strong>
        </h1>
        <p id="text">{this.props.quote}</p>
        <p id="author" style={{ textAlign : "right", margin : "10px" }}><em>- DG</em></p>
        <button id="new-quote" style={{ marginRight: '4%' }} onClick={this.showQuote}>Quote</button>
        <a id="tweet-quote" class="button" style={{ textAlign: 'center', float: 'left' }} title="Tweet this quote!" href="twitter.com/intent/tweet">
          <i class="fa fa-twitter" />
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What have your tried so far? Can you post the code?

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I have not really tried anything yet; so far, I've only been brainstorming and weighing my choices. I have posted the part of the code that renders all the current elements; additionally, I included the method responsible for handling submissions (pressing the "submit" button).